# GNU Make for loop with two variables

Tags: makefile, gnu

I want to write something along these lines:

```
$(foreach (var1, var2), ($(LIST1), $(LIST2)), cp $(var1) $(var2);)
```

How do I go about doing this in a GNU makefile?

Comment: Also as I am writing this thing out the long way I realized I will need it outside a rule.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Beta's suggestion to use join is on the right track, but the problem is that it's not so easy to use it in a way that constructs a command line containing whitespace, such as the one you originally wanted:

```
$(foreach (var1, var2), ($(LIST1), $(LIST2)), cp $(var1) $(var2);)
```

because join joins words together: it was originally intended for constructing filenames.  However you can play a trick; here's an example of a way to use join that gives you the output you are looking for:

```
$(subst ^, ,$(join $(addprefix cp^,$(LIST1)),$(patsubst %,^%;,$(LIST2))))
```

If you think your lists might contain `^` characters then choose something else.  Let me know if you need this unpacked/explained.

Answer (score 3):

```
LIST1 := a b c
LIST2 := 1 2 3

# outside a rule:
$(foreach var1, a b c, $(foreach var2, 1 2 3, $(info $(var1)_$(var2))))

# inside a rule: first line starts with a TAB, all the rest are spaces
all:
    @for x in $(LIST1);\
    do \
      for y in $(LIST2);\
      do\
        echo $$x $$y; \
      done \
    done
```

(Please note that a nested loop that does `cp` doesn't make much sense.)

**EDIT:**
Well why didn't you say so?

```
LIST3 := $(join $(LIST1),$(LIST2))
```

Comment: Yup because I dont want the cross product I need a one to one mapping. That is what has my brain going in loops.

Comment: Sooooo... you've marked this answer as correct.  It doesn't seem to answer the question you had though.  Is this what you wanted, or not?

Comment: That is not the answer I wanted, but no one answered after a few days, so I marked it as the most relativly correct answer. If you have a better answer please post.

Comment: @MatthewHoggan, I didn't understand your comment. You mean you want a result like `a1 b2 c3`?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong if I have a list (a, b, c) and (1, 2, 3) and I run the scripts above I get a,1 a,2 a,3, b,1, b,2, b,3, ... When I want a,1 b,2 c,3

Answer (score 1):

This is a good candidate for  [gsml](http://gmsl.sourceforge.net/) (GNU Make Standard Library). You can include it by putting the files `__gmsl` and `gml` in the current directory (or in `/usr/gnu/include`, `/usr/local/include/` etc.) and adding the line `include gsml` in your Makefile. It includes the `pairmap` function, which does exactly what you want (i.e. `zipWith`).

```
include gmsl
cp2 = cp $1 $2;
zip = $1 : $2
$(LIST2):
    @echo $(call pairmap, zip, $(LIST1), $(LIST2))
    $(call pairmap, cp2, $(LIST1), $(LIST2))
```

Outputs

```
$ make 
A : 1 B : 2 C : 3 D : 4
cp A 1; cp B 2; cp C 3; cp D 4;
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit old post but I found this lets you do exactly what you need. You will need the `seq` utility which is a Unix utility and will be available on Linux and Mac.

I wrote the example with printing variables but it should work with copying.

```
# Two lists
LIST1 = a1 a2 a3 a4
LIST2 = b1 b2 b3 b4

# This will generate
# LISTSEQ=1 2 3 4
LISTSEQ=$(shell seq $(words $(LIST1)))

# Print variable for example
define printvar
$(info $(1))
$(info $(2))
endef

# First line loops through 1 2 3 4
# and next line prints the corresponding value from LIST1 and LIST2
$(foreach j, $(LISTSEQ), \
    $(call printvar,$(word $(j), $(LIST1)) $(word $(j), $(LIST2))) \
)
```

Output:

```
a1 b1

a2 b2

a3 b3

a4 b4
```

Comment: This is excellent. You need commas inside the loop though, otherwise nothing is being assigned to $(2), just both to $(1). `$(call printvar,$(word $(j), $(LIST1)),$(word $(j), $(LIST2)))`